# SSRS with 'Available Values By Query' does not return ValidValues property

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

I have a web application using a SSRS 2010 service, and I'm having an issue getting back the valid values for a parameter.  The parameter allows multiple values and is of type Text.  In the report I create, I am **getting available values by query**, as opposed to 'specify values'.  When I call [GetItemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemparameters.aspx) the ValidValues property is empty.

If my Report **specifies values** instead of getting values from query, then the ValidValues property is filled in completely.

I'm hoping someone knows a way to get that property filled out when getting from query, because I'd hate to have my report writers specifying hundreds of (often changing) values individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your link ReportingService2010.GetItemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemparameters.aspx)  gives following information

> If any parameters values are based on a query and you are interested
>   in returning the query-based parameters' valid values list, set
>   ForRendering to true. In addition, for query-based parameters, you
>   must pass in all of the credential information required to return the
>   query parameters.

Did you set ForRendering to true value as it is said in this link?